# GET url connection with Json ios - swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, nsurl, nsmutableurlrequest

I'm learning swift and I need to make a GET request, so this is my code:

```
    var j = ["user": "xxxxxx@xxxxxx.xxx"]
    var e: NSError?
    let jsonData = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(j,options: NSJSONWritingOptions(0),error: &e) 
    var jsonString = NSString(data: jsonData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    var urlPath = "http://test.example.io/materials?query=\(jsonString)";
    println(urlPath)

    var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)
    var request: NSMutableURLRequest =  NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.addValue("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" , forHTTPHeaderField: "Teech-Application-Id")
    request.addValue("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" , forHTTPHeaderField: "Teech-REST-API-Key")
    request.addValue("application/json" , forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

    println(request)
```

And this is my output debug

```
http://test.example.io/materials?query={"user":"xxxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxx.xxxxx"}

<NSMutableURLRequest: 0x7f8ee3480320> { URL: (null), headers: {
"Content-Type" = "application/json";
"Teech-Application-Id" = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;
"Teech-REST-API-Key" = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;
} }
```

Why the first print function return the correct url and inside the print request there is a null url, where is my mistake ? I've tried with a url without a json and it runs.

Comment: Because `http://test.example.io/materials?query={"user":"xxxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxx.xxxxx"}` is not a valid url and `NSURL` failed to initialize an instance from it?

Comment: I have replaced the real url in this example, but i have a good url. In fact with a url without a json (http://test.example.io/materials) it runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I done it, the solution is escaping the string.

```
var escapedSearchTerm = urlPath.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: escapedSearchTerm!)
```